# p:selectonemenu onkeyup event to uppercase

Tags: jsf, primefaces, uppercase, selectonemenu, keyup

I am using `p:selectOneMenu` for displaying data. I am using `filter="true"` and `filterMatchMode="startsWith"` for filtering data:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="mun" value="#{list}" converter="#{lookupConverter}"
                 filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" 
                 validator="#{validate}">
    <p:ajax listener="#{getAll}" update="plac"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['choose.value']}" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{municipalities}"
                   var="m"
                   itemValue="#{m}"
                   itemLabel="#{m.description}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

And I like when user start typing in textbox onkeyup event entered text to be upper case.

Edit:

When I say text box I mean on this red square:

[image]

Comment: where is the textbox? is the menu editable?

Answer (score 0):

When you inspect the page where the menu is placed, you can see that the input filter has more or less following id:

```
j_idt88:advanced_filter
```

Based on that and the fact that this input will be always suffixed with `advanced_filter`.. you can write your javascript code:

```
<script>
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
       addAdvancedFilterActions();
   }, false);

   var addAdvancedFilterActions = function(){
         var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id$=advanced_filter]');

        for (var key in addAdvancedFilterActions) {
           var input = addAdvancedFilterActions[key];
           input.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
                 upper(input);
              },false);
        }
   };

   var upper = function(input){
          var inputValue = input.value;
          document.writeIn(inputValue.toUpperCase())
   };

</script>
```

This will iterate through all inputs like this on the page and apply the upper function. Try it out